# Transform xml file into r dataframe

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

Using R Studio 1.0.44 on a MacOS 10.12.1

This is my first time working with xml files and I'm having quite a bit of trouble..
I want to turn my xml file into an r data frame that looks something like this:

```
Date    househouldid    memberid    session begin   end
11/1/15 4FDYT14A1Q             1      235   49448   49453
11/1/15 4FDYT14A1Q             1    1010001 49453   49463
11/1/15 4FDYT14A1Q             1    1010475 49463   49468
```

I only want Date, householdid, memberid, session, begin and end in the data frame.

I tried...

```
xmldataframe<-xmlToDataFrame("DQA_audxml_20150105_EN.xml")
print(xmldataframe)
```

and got this...

> destinations members regular_guests occasional_guests tvsets household_process

Here's part of the xml file (I'm restricted by the character count)..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<households date="2015-01-05" creation_date="2015-01-11T04:22:35" xmlns:s="http://www.mediametrie.fr/nge/schemas" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan">
  <household id="95D7N14AFA">
    <destinations />
    <members>
      <member id="1">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="2">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="3">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
    </members>
    <regular_guests />
    <occasional_guests />
    <tvsets>
      <tvset id="1">
        <tvset_process result="OK">
          <tvset_audience />
          <alarms>
            <alarm id="AL_T_P_VALID_LAST_HOUR_REBOOT" rule_id="T_P_METER_STOPPING_TIMESTAMPING">
              <parameters>
                <parameter name="unique_id" value="149" />
                <parameter name="reboot_date" value="2015-01-05T03:34:23" />
                <parameter name="length" value="0.35116898148148146" />
              </parameters>
            </alarm>
            <alarm id="AL_T_P_VALID_LAST_HOUR_REBOOT" rule_id="T_P_METER_STOPPING_TIMESTAMPING">
              <parameters>
                <parameter name="unique_id" value="150" />
                <parameter name="reboot_date" value="2015-01-05T05:28:34" />
                <parameter name="length" value="0.02806712962962963" />
              </parameters>
            </alarm>
            <alarm id="AL_T_P_VALID_LAST_HOUR_REBOOT" rule_id="T_P_METER_STOPPING_TIMESTAMPING">
              <parameters>
                <parameter name="unique_id" value="151" />
                <parameter name="reboot_date" value="2015-01-05T08:22:46" />
                <parameter name="length" value="0.07322916666666666" />
              </parameters>
            </alarm>
            <alarm id="AL_T_P_VALID_LAST_HOUR_REBOOT" rule_id="T_P_METER_STOPPING_TIMESTAMPING">
              <parameters>
                <parameter name="unique_id" value="152" />
                <parameter name="reboot_date" value="2015-01-05T14:32:43" />
                <parameter name="length" value="0.004803240740740742" />
              </parameters>
            </alarm>
            <alarm id="AL_T_P_VALID_LAST_HOUR_REBOOT" rule_id="T_P_METER_STOPPING_TIMESTAMPING">
              <parameters>
                <parameter name="unique_id" value="153" />
                <parameter name="reboot_date" value="2015-01-05T18:30:47" />
                <parameter name="length" value="0.0012384259259259258" />
              </parameters>
            </alarm>
            <alarm id="AL_T_P_VALID_LAST_HOUR_REBOOT" rule_id="T_P_METER_STOPPING_TIMESTAMPING">
              <parameters>
                <parameter name="unique_id" value="154" />
                <parameter name="reboot_date" value="2015-01-06T02:52:01" />
                <parameter name="length" value="0.33817129629629633" />
              </parameters>
            </alarm>
          </alarms>
        </tvset_process>
      </tvset>
    </tvsets>
    <household_process result="OK" vacation="no">
      <alarms />
    </household_process>
  </household>
  <household id="ISDPN14ASG">
    <destinations />
    <members>
      <member id="1">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="2">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="3">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="4">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="5">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
    </members>
    <regular_guests />
    <occasional_guests />
    <tvsets>
      <tvset id="1">
        <tvset_process result="KO">
          <tvset_audience />
          <alarms>
            <alarm id="AL_R_P_EVENT_CHRONOLOGY" rule_id="R_P_EVENT_CHRONOLOGY">
              <parameters>
                <parameter name="unique_id" value="16195" />
              </parameters>
            </alarm>
            <alarm id="AL_PROCESS_STOP" rule_id="R_P_EVENT_CHRONOLOGY">
              <parameters />
            </alarm>
          </alarms>
        </tvset_process>
      </tvset>
    </tvsets>
    <household_process result="KO" vacation="no">
      <alarms>
        <alarm id="AL_T_FP_HOUSEHOLD_ABS_DECLARATION" rule_id="T_FP_HOUSEHOLD_ABS_DECLARATION">
          <parameters />
        </alarm>
        <alarm id="AL_R_FP_NO_TVSET_KO" rule_id="R_FP_NO_TVSET_KO">
          <parameters>
            <parameter name="tvset_id" value="1" />
          </parameters>
        </alarm>
        <alarm id="AL_R_FP_AT_LEAST_ONE_TVSET_OK" rule_id="R_FP_AT_LEAST_ONE_TVSET_OK">
          <parameters />
        </alarm>
      </alarms>
    </household_process>
  </household>
  <household id="4FDYT14A1Q">
    <destinations />
    <members>
      <member id="1">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="2">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience>
            <individual_audience_tvset id="1">
              <channel session="1010497" begin="46722" end="46738" />
              <channel session="48" begin="46738" end="46743" />
              <channel session="235" begin="46743" end="46748" />
              <channel session="47" begin="46748" end="46753" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="46753" end="46973" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="46973" end="46983" />
              <channel session="1010319" begin="46983" end="46993" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="46993" end="47578" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="47578" end="47618" />
              <channel session="47" begin="47618" end="47633" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="47633" end="47693" />
              <channel session="48" begin="47693" end="47703" />
              <channel session="235" begin="47703" end="47728" />
              <channel session="1010469" begin="47728" end="47778" />
              <channel session="235" begin="47778" end="47783" />
              <channel session="48" begin="47783" end="47828" />
              <channel session="1010367" begin="47828" end="47853" />
              <channel session="48" begin="47853" end="48373" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="48373" end="48573" />
              <channel session="48" begin="48573" end="49433" />
              <channel session="1010452" begin="49433" end="49448" />
              <channel session="235" begin="49448" end="49453" />
              <channel session="1010001" begin="49453" end="49463" />
              <channel session="1010475" begin="49463" end="49468" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="49468" end="49483" />
              <channel session="48" begin="49483" end="49508" />
              <channel session="1010403" begin="49508" end="49543" />
              <channel session="48" begin="49543" end="53839" />
              <channel session="1010354" begin="60868" end="60878" />
              <channel session="235" begin="60878" end="60893" />
              <channel session="48" begin="60893" end="60908" />
              <channel session="235" begin="60908" end="60913" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="60913" end="60928" />
              <channel session="48" begin="60928" end="60933" />
              <channel session="235" begin="60933" end="60938" />
              <channel session="48" begin="60938" end="60943" />
              <channel session="235" begin="60943" end="60953" />
              <channel session="48" begin="60953" end="60968" />
              <channel session="235" begin="60968" end="60993" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="60993" end="61483" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="61483" end="61538" />
              <channel session="48" begin="61538" end="61543" />
              <channel session="47" begin="61543" end="61578" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="61578" end="61603" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="61603" end="63428" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="63428" end="63438" />
              <channel session="1010319" begin="63438" end="63888" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="63888" end="63898" />
              <channel session="235" begin="63898" end="63903" />
              <channel session="47" begin="63903" end="64368" />
              <channel session="48" begin="64368" end="64373" />
              <channel session="47" begin="64373" end="64378" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="64378" end="64393" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="64393" end="64408" />
              <channel session="1010001" begin="64408" end="64423" />
              <channel session="235" begin="64423" end="64428" />
              <channel session="1010469" begin="64428" end="64468" />
              <channel session="1010452" begin="64468" end="64473" />
              <channel session="48" begin="64473" end="64528" />
              <channel session="1010367" begin="64528" end="65053" />
              <channel session="48" begin="65053" end="65328" />
              <channel session="1010367" begin="65328" end="66613" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="66613" end="66628" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="66628" end="66823" />
              <channel session="47" begin="66823" end="66833" />
              <channel session="1010367" begin="66833" end="67538" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="67538" end="67553" />
              <channel session="1010354" begin="67553" end="67563" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="67563" end="67658" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="67658" end="67713" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="67713" end="67733" />
              <channel session="1010367" begin="67733" end="67803" />
              <channel session="48" begin="67803" end="68018" />
              <channel session="1010367" begin="68018" end="70963" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="70963" end="71048" />
              <channel session="1010367" begin="71048" end="71848" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="71848" end="72023" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="72023" end="72043" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="72043" end="72068" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="72068" end="72083" />
              <channel session="47" begin="72083" end="72098" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="72098" end="73643" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="73643" end="73668" />
              <channel session="1010354" begin="73668" end="73683" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="73683" end="73693" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="73693" end="73708" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="73708" end="73748" />
              <channel session="235" begin="73748" end="73753" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="73753" end="73763" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="73763" end="74323" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="74323" end="74363" />
              <channel session="1010354" begin="74363" end="74378" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="74378" end="74443" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="74443" end="74453" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="74453" end="74883" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="74883" end="74938" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="74938" end="74953" />
              <channel session="47" begin="74953" end="75603" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="75603" end="77673" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="77673" end="79208" />
              <channel session="1010354" begin="79208" end="79228" />
              <channel session="235" begin="79228" end="79233" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="79233" end="79603" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="79603" end="80088" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="80088" end="80238" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="80238" end="80253" />
              <channel session="235" begin="80253" end="80258" />
              <channel session="47" begin="80258" end="80423" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="80423" end="80678" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="80678" end="80688" />
              <channel session="47" begin="80688" end="80853" />
              <channel session="235" begin="80853" end="80858" />
              <channel session="1010354" begin="80858" end="80868" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="80868" end="81428" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="81428" end="81438" />
              <channel session="235" begin="81438" end="81448" />
              <channel session="47" begin="81448" end="81453" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="81453" end="82108" />
              <channel session="1010354" begin="82108" end="82528" />
              <channel session="1010497" begin="82528" end="82538" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="82538" end="82548" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="82548" end="82608" />
              <channel session="47" begin="82608" end="82628" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="82628" end="82648" />
              <channel session="1010354" begin="82648" end="82973" />
              <channel session="1010072" begin="82973" end="82983" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="82983" end="83273" />
              <channel session="47" begin="83273" end="83313" />
              <channel session="1010383" begin="83313" end="83393" />
              <channel session="1010319" begin="83393" end="83443" />
              <channel session="1010499" begin="83443" end="83498" />
              <channel session="48" begin="83498" end="83688" />
              <channel session="47" begin="83688" end="83883" />
              <channel session="48" begin="83883" end="83898" />
              <channel session="1010258" begin="83898" end="84193" />
              <channel session="47" begin="84193" end="84198" />
              <channel session="1010260" begin="84198" end="84253" />
              <channel session="235" begin="84253" end="84258" />
              <channel session="47" begin="84258" end="84273" />
              <channel session="48" begin="84273" end="84423" />
              <channel session="235" begin="84423" end="84433" />
              <channel session="48" begin="84433" end="84448" />
              <channel session="1010260" begin="84448" end="84463" />
              <channel session="1010144" begin="84463" end="84578" />
              <channel session="235" begin="84578" end="84583" />
              <channel session="1010260" begin="84583" end="84628" />
              <channel session="235" begin="84628" end="84633" />
              <channel session="1010258" begin="84633" end="84643" />
              <channel session="48" begin="84643" end="85088" />
              <channel session="235" begin="85088" end="85098" />
              <channel session="1010258" begin="85098" end="85113" />
              <channel session="235" begin="85113" end="85118" />
              <channel session="1010144" begin="85118" end="85163" />
              <channel session="1010260" begin="85163" end="85178" />
              <channel session="48" begin="85178" end="85398" />
              <channel session="1010493" begin="85398" end="85418" />
              <channel session="48" begin="85418" end="85428" />
              <channel session="235" begin="85428" end="85433" />
              <channel session="47" begin="85433" end="85488" />
              <channel session="1010260" begin="85488" end="85493" />
              <channel session="1010258" begin="85493" end="85638" />
              <channel session="1010474" begin="85638" end="85785" />
            </individual_audience_tvset>
          </individual_audience>
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="3">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience>
            <individual_audience_tvset id="1">
              <channel session="1010493" begin="54476" end="54490" />
              <channel session="47" begin="54490" end="55035" />
              <channel session="1010379" begin="55035" end="55210" />
              <channel session="48" begin="55210" end="55220" />
              <channel session="1010397" begin="55220" end="55570" />
              <channel session="235" begin="55570" end="55580" />
              <channel session="1010425" begin="55580" end="55585" />
              <channel session="1010397" begin="55585" end="55620" />
              <channel session="235" begin="55620" end="55625" />
              <channel session="48" begin="55625" end="56875" />
              <channel session="1010379" begin="56875" end="57345" />
              <channel session="48" begin="57345" end="57615" />
              <channel session="1010379" begin="57615" end="57865" />
              <channel session="48" begin="57865" end="58079" />
            </individual_audience_tvset>
          </individual_audience>
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
      <member id="4">
        <member_process result="OK" vacation="undefined">
          <individual_audience />
          <alarms />
        </member_process>
      </member>
    </members>
    <regular_guests />
    <occasional_guests />
    <tvsets>
      <tvset id="1">
        <tvset_process result="OK">
          <tvset_audience>
            <channel session="1010497" begin="46708" end="46738" />
            <channel session="48" begin="46738" end="46743" />
            <channel session="235" begin="46743" end="46748" />
            <channel session="47" begin="46748" end="46753" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="46753" end="46973" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="46973" end="46983" />
            <channel session="1010319" begin="46983" end="46993" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="46993" end="47578" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="47578" end="47618" />
            <channel session="47" begin="47618" end="47633" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="47633" end="47693" />
            <channel session="48" begin="47693" end="47703" />
            <channel session="235" begin="47703" end="47728" />
            <channel session="1010469" begin="47728" end="47778" />
            <channel session="235" begin="47778" end="47783" />
            <channel session="48" begin="47783" end="47828" />
            <channel session="1010367" begin="47828" end="47853" />
            <channel session="48" begin="47853" end="48373" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="48373" end="48573" />
            <channel session="48" begin="48573" end="49433" />
            <channel session="1010452" begin="49433" end="49448" />
            <channel session="235" begin="49448" end="49453" />
            <channel session="1010001" begin="49453" end="49463" />
            <channel session="1010475" begin="49463" end="49468" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="49468" end="49483" />
            <channel session="48" begin="49483" end="49508" />
            <channel session="1010403" begin="49508" end="49543" />
            <channel session="48" begin="49543" end="53839" />
            <channel session="1010493" begin="54460" end="54490" />
            <channel session="47" begin="54490" end="55035" />
            <channel session="1010379" begin="55035" end="55210" />
            <channel session="48" begin="55210" end="55220" />
            <channel session="1010397" begin="55220" end="55570" />
            <channel session="235" begin="55570" end="55580" />
            <channel session="1010425" begin="55580" end="55585" />
            <channel session="1010397" begin="55585" end="55620" />
            <channel session="235" begin="55620" end="55625" />
            <channel session="48" begin="55625" end="56875" />
            <channel session="1010379" begin="56875" end="57345" />
            <channel session="48" begin="57345" end="57615" />
            <channel session="1010379" begin="57615" end="57865" />
            <channel session="48" begin="57865" end="58079" />
            <channel session="1010354" begin="60848" end="60878" />
            <channel session="235" begin="60878" end="60893" />
            <channel session="48" begin="60893" end="60908" />
            <channel session="235" begin="60908" end="60913" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="60913" end="60928" />
            <channel session="48" begin="60928" end="60933" />
            <channel session="235" begin="60933" end="60938" />
            <channel session="48" begin="60938" end="60943" />
            <channel session="235" begin="60943" end="60953" />
            <channel session="48" begin="60953" end="60968" />
            <channel session="235" begin="60968" end="60993" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="60993" end="61483" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="61483" end="61538" />
            <channel session="48" begin="61538" end="61543" />
            <channel session="47" begin="61543" end="61578" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="61578" end="61603" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="61603" end="63428" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="63428" end="63438" />
            <channel session="1010319" begin="63438" end="63888" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="63888" end="63898" />
            <channel session="235" begin="63898" end="63903" />
            <channel session="47" begin="63903" end="64368" />
            <channel session="48" begin="64368" end="64373" />
            <channel session="47" begin="64373" end="64378" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="64378" end="64393" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="64393" end="64408" />
            <channel session="1010001" begin="64408" end="64423" />
            <channel session="235" begin="64423" end="64428" />
            <channel session="1010469" begin="64428" end="64468" />
            <channel session="1010452" begin="64468" end="64473" />
            <channel session="48" begin="64473" end="64528" />
            <channel session="1010367" begin="64528" end="65053" />
            <channel session="48" begin="65053" end="65328" />
            <channel session="1010367" begin="65328" end="66613" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="66613" end="66628" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="66628" end="66823" />
            <channel session="47" begin="66823" end="66833" />
            <channel session="1010367" begin="66833" end="67538" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="67538" end="67553" />
            <channel session="1010354" begin="67553" end="67563" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="67563" end="67658" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="67658" end="67713" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="67713" end="67733" />
            <channel session="1010367" begin="67733" end="67803" />
            <channel session="48" begin="67803" end="68018" />
            <channel session="1010367" begin="68018" end="70963" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="70963" end="71048" />
            <channel session="1010367" begin="71048" end="71848" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="71848" end="72023" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="72023" end="72043" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="72043" end="72068" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="72068" end="72083" />
            <channel session="47" begin="72083" end="72098" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="72098" end="73643" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="73643" end="73668" />
            <channel session="1010354" begin="73668" end="73683" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="73683" end="73693" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="73693" end="73708" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="73708" end="73748" />
            <channel session="235" begin="73748" end="73753" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="73753" end="73763" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="73763" end="74323" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="74323" end="74363" />
            <channel session="1010354" begin="74363" end="74378" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="74378" end="74443" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="74443" end="74453" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="74453" end="74883" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="74883" end="74938" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="74938" end="74953" />
            <channel session="47" begin="74953" end="75603" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="75603" end="77673" />
            <channel session="1010383" begin="77673" end="79208" />
            <channel session="1010354" begin="79208" end="79228" />
            <channel session="235" begin="79228" end="79233" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="79233" end="79603" />
            <channel session="1010072" begin="79603" end="80088" />
            <channel session="1010497" begin="80088" end="80238" />
            <channel session="1010499" begin="80238" end="80253" />
            <channel session="235" begin="80253" end="80258" />
```

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787171/transforming-data-from-xml-into-r-dataframe/40790195#40790195 .  Using the solution marked (2)  there instead of looping on `//test`, loop on `//channel` getting its `session`, `begin` and `end` attributes.  Reach back through its ancestors to get the `id` attribute of its `member` node ancestor , the `id` attribute of its `household` node ancestor and `date` attribute of its `households` node ancestor.  Alternately with a bit more work you could follow the faster solution marked (1).

Comment: Thanks Grothendieck!

Answer (score 2):

This is all just elbow grease and being familiar with how XML is structured. The relatively new `purrr` package is very useful here. But, I think your question is still a bit vague and the lack of a valid XML file is more than problematic:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

hh <- read_xml("~/data/so.xml")

xml_find_all(hh, ".//household") %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    id <- xml_attr(x, "id")
    members <- xml_find_all(x, ".//member")
    map_df(members, function(y) {
      channel_sessions <- xml_find_all(y, ".//channel")
      if (length(channel_sessions) == 0) {
        NULL
      } else {
        xml_attrs(channel_sessions) %>% 
          map_df(as.list) %>% 
          mutate(memberid=xml_attr(y, "id"),
                 household=id)
      }
    })
  }) %>% 
  mutate(date=xml_find_first(hh, "//households") %>% 
           xml_attr("creation_date") %>% 
           as.Date())
## # A tibble: 176 × 6
##    session begin   end memberid  household       date
##      <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     <date>
## 1  1010497 46722 46738        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 2       48 46738 46743        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 3      235 46743 46748        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 4       47 46748 46753        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 5  1010383 46753 46973        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 6  1010497 46973 46983        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 7  1010319 46983 46993        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 8  1010072 46993 47578        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 9  1010499 47578 47618        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## 10      47 47618 47633        2 4FDYT14A1Q 2015-01-11
## # ... with 166 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

With words of *transform* and *xml* in same title, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform source XML files into end use needs such as import into R dataframes. Now the challenge presented is R does not have a dedicated library to run XSLT.

Nonetheless, R can call command lines to [external processers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) (even in other languages like Python, PHP, Java, etc.) to convert input to output. Below are two versions: for Windows (using Powershell's call to [XslCompiledTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx)) and Linux/Mac (using [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) usually installed on most distributions):

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl, a well-formed xml file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/households">   
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="household"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="household|members|member|member_process|individual_audience|individual_audience_tvset">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="channel">
    <tvset>
      <date><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::households/@date"/></date>
      <household_id><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::household/@id"/></household_id>
      <member_id><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::member/@id"/></member_id>
      <session><xsl:value-of select="@session"/></session>
      <begin><xsl:value-of select="@begin"/></begin>
      <end><xsl:value-of select="@end"/></end>
    </tvset>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tvsets"/>   
</xsl:transform>
```

**PowerShell** Script *(save as .ps1 file, for Windows only)*

```bsh
param ($xml, $xsl, $output)

if (-not $xml -or -not $xsl -or -not $output) {
    Write-Host "& .\xslt.ps1 [-xml] xml-input [-xsl] xsl-input [-output] transform-output"
    exit;
}

trap [Exception]{
    Write-Host $_.Exception;
}

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.Load($xsl);
$xslt.Transform($xml, $output);

Write-Host "generated" $output;
```

**R** *(Windows)*

```
library(XML)

system(paste0('Powershell.exe -File',
              ' "C:\\Path\\To\\PowerShell\\Script.ps1"',
              ' "C:\\Path\\To\\Input.xml"',
              ' "C:\\Path\\To\\XSLT\\Script.xsl"', 
              ' "C:\\Path\\To\\Output.xml"'))

df <- xmlToDataFrame("C:\\Path\\To\\Output.xml")

head(df, 10)
#          date household_id member_id session begin   end
# 1  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2 1010497 46722 46738
# 2  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2      48 46738 46743
# 3  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2     235 46743 46748
# 4  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2      47 46748 46753
# 5  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2 1010383 46753 46973
# 6  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2 1010497 46973 46983
# 7  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2 1010319 46983 46993
# 8  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2 1010072 46993 47578
# 9  2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2 1010499 47578 47618
# 10 2015-01-05   4FDYT14A1Q         2      47 47618 47633
```

**R** *(Linux/Mac)*

```
library(XML)

system('xsltproc /path/to/XSLT_Script.xsl /path/to/Input.xml -o path/to/Output.xml')

df <- xmlToDataFrame("path/to/Output.xml")
```