# XML data to R dataframes

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I have a XML file which was returned by a java application to find the optimal route in a transportation problem. Want to use this output file in R. I have used "XML" package in R. IN the XML file there is a node called "VehicleList", if possible just the path of each vehicle is also sufficient.

XML FILE:

```
<VrpVehicleRoutingSolution id="1">
  <id>0</id>
  <name>A-n33-k6</name>
  <distanceType>AIR_DISTANCE</distanceType>
  <distanceUnitOfMeasurement>distance</distanceUnitOfMeasurement>
  <locationList id="2">
    <VrpAirLocation id="3">
      <id>1</id>
      <latitude>34.0</latitude>
      <longitude>31.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="4">
      <id>2</id>
      <latitude>45.0</latitude>
      <longitude>55.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="5">
      <id>3</id>
      <latitude>70.0</latitude>
      <longitude>80.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="6">
      <id>4</id>
      <latitude>81.0</latitude>
      <longitude>70.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="7">
      <id>5</id>
      <latitude>85.0</latitude>
      <longitude>61.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="8">
      <id>6</id>
      <latitude>59.0</latitude>
      <longitude>55.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="9">
      <id>7</id>
      <latitude>45.0</latitude>
      <longitude>60.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="10">
      <id>8</id>
      <latitude>50.0</latitude>
      <longitude>64.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="11">
      <id>9</id>
      <latitude>80.0</latitude>
      <longitude>64.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="12">
      <id>10</id>
      <latitude>75.0</latitude>
      <longitude>90.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="13">
      <id>11</id>
      <latitude>25.0</latitude>
      <longitude>40.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="14">
      <id>12</id>
      <latitude>9.0</latitude>
      <longitude>66.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="15">
      <id>13</id>
      <latitude>1.0</latitude>
      <longitude>44.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="16">
      <id>14</id>
      <latitude>50.0</latitude>
      <longitude>54.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="17">
      <id>15</id>
      <latitude>35.0</latitude>
      <longitude>45.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="18">
      <id>16</id>
      <latitude>71.0</latitude>
      <longitude>84.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="19">
      <id>17</id>
      <latitude>1.0</latitude>
      <longitude>9.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="20">
      <id>18</id>
      <latitude>25.0</latitude>
      <longitude>54.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="21">
      <id>19</id>
      <latitude>45.0</latitude>
      <longitude>59.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="22">
      <id>20</id>
      <latitude>45.0</latitude>
      <longitude>71.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="23">
      <id>21</id>
      <latitude>66.0</latitude>
      <longitude>84.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="24">
      <id>22</id>
      <latitude>11.0</latitude>
      <longitude>35.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="25">
      <id>23</id>
      <latitude>81.0</latitude>
      <longitude>46.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="26">
      <id>24</id>
      <latitude>85.0</latitude>
      <longitude>10.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="27">
      <id>25</id>
      <latitude>75.0</latitude>
      <longitude>20.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="28">
      <id>26</id>
      <latitude>15.0</latitude>
      <longitude>21.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="29">
      <id>27</id>
      <latitude>90.0</latitude>
      <longitude>45.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="30">
      <id>28</id>
      <latitude>15.0</latitude>
      <longitude>0.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="31">
      <id>29</id>
      <latitude>31.0</latitude>
      <longitude>26.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="32">
      <id>30</id>
      <latitude>10.0</latitude>
      <longitude>95.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="33">
      <id>31</id>
      <latitude>6.0</latitude>
      <longitude>6.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="34">
      <id>32</id>
      <latitude>51.0</latitude>
      <longitude>5.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
    <VrpAirLocation id="35">
      <id>33</id>
      <latitude>26.0</latitude>
      <longitude>36.0</longitude>
    </VrpAirLocation>
  </locationList>
  <depotList id="36">
    <VrpDepot id="37">
      <id>1</id>
      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="3"/>
    </VrpDepot>
  </depotList>
  <vehicleList id="38">
    <VrpVehicle id="39">
      <id>0</id>
      <capacity>100</capacity>
      <depot reference="37"/>
      <nextCustomer id="40">
        <id>33</id>
        <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="35"/>
        <demand>22</demand>
        <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="39"/>
        <nextCustomer id="41">
          <id>11</id>
          <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="13"/>
          <demand>1</demand>
          <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="40"/>
          <nextCustomer id="42">
            <id>12</id>
            <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="14"/>
            <demand>21</demand>
            <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="41"/>
            <nextCustomer id="43">
              <id>30</id>
              <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="32"/>
              <demand>22</demand>
              <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="42"/>
              <nextCustomer id="44">
                <id>18</id>
                <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="20"/>
                <demand>17</demand>
                <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="43"/>
                <vehicle reference="39"/>
              </nextCustomer>
              <vehicle reference="39"/>
            </nextCustomer>
            <vehicle reference="39"/>
          </nextCustomer>
          <vehicle reference="39"/>
        </nextCustomer>
        <vehicle reference="39"/>
      </nextCustomer>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="45">
      <id>1</id>
      <capacity>100</capacity>
      <depot reference="37"/>
      <nextCustomer id="46">
        <id>14</id>
        <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="16"/>
        <demand>25</demand>
        <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="45"/>
        <nextCustomer id="47">
          <id>8</id>
          <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="10"/>
          <demand>15</demand>
          <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="46"/>
          <nextCustomer id="48">
            <id>19</id>
            <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="21"/>
            <demand>17</demand>
            <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="47"/>
            <nextCustomer id="49">
              <id>2</id>
              <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="4"/>
              <demand>26</demand>
              <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="48"/>
              <nextCustomer id="50">
                <id>15</id>
                <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="17"/>
                <demand>16</demand>
                <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="49"/>
                <vehicle reference="45"/>
              </nextCustomer>
              <vehicle reference="45"/>
            </nextCustomer>
            <vehicle reference="45"/>
          </nextCustomer>
          <vehicle reference="45"/>
        </nextCustomer>
        <vehicle reference="45"/>
      </nextCustomer>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="51">
      <id>2</id>
      <capacity>100</capacity>
      <depot reference="37"/>
      <nextCustomer id="52">
        <id>13</id>
        <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="15"/>
        <demand>66</demand>
        <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="51"/>
        <nextCustomer id="53">
          <id>22</id>
          <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="24"/>
          <demand>25</demand>
          <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="52"/>
          <vehicle reference="51"/>
        </nextCustomer>
        <vehicle reference="51"/>
      </nextCustomer>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="54">
      <id>3</id>
      <capacity>100</capacity>
      <depot reference="37"/>
      <nextCustomer id="55">
        <id>29</id>
        <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="31"/>
        <demand>21</demand>
        <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="54"/>
        <nextCustomer id="56">
          <id>28</id>
          <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="30"/>
          <demand>11</demand>
          <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="55"/>
          <nextCustomer id="57">
            <id>31</id>
            <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="33"/>
            <demand>25</demand>
            <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="56"/>
            <nextCustomer id="58">
              <id>17</id>
              <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="19"/>
              <demand>7</demand>
              <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="57"/>
              <nextCustomer id="59">
                <id>26</id>
                <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="28"/>
                <demand>11</demand>
                <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="58"/>
                <vehicle reference="54"/>
              </nextCustomer>
              <vehicle reference="54"/>
            </nextCustomer>
            <vehicle reference="54"/>
          </nextCustomer>
          <vehicle reference="54"/>
        </nextCustomer>
        <vehicle reference="54"/>
      </nextCustomer>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="60">
      <id>4</id>
      <capacity>100</capacity>
      <depot reference="37"/>
      <nextCustomer id="61">
        <id>32</id>
        <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="34"/>
        <demand>2</demand>
        <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="60"/>
        <nextCustomer id="62">
          <id>24</id>
          <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="26"/>
          <demand>7</demand>
          <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="61"/>
          <nextCustomer id="63">
            <id>25</id>
            <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="27"/>
            <demand>21</demand>
            <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="62"/>
            <nextCustomer id="64">
              <id>23</id>
              <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="25"/>
              <demand>16</demand>
              <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="63"/>
              <nextCustomer id="65">
                <id>27</id>
                <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="29"/>
                <demand>21</demand>
                <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="64"/>
                <nextCustomer id="66">
                  <id>5</id>
                  <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="7"/>
                  <demand>15</demand>
                  <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="65"/>
                  <nextCustomer id="67">
                    <id>9</id>
                    <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="11"/>
                    <demand>16</demand>
                    <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="66"/>
                    <vehicle reference="60"/>
                  </nextCustomer>
                  <vehicle reference="60"/>
                </nextCustomer>
                <vehicle reference="60"/>
              </nextCustomer>
              <vehicle reference="60"/>
            </nextCustomer>
            <vehicle reference="60"/>
          </nextCustomer>
          <vehicle reference="60"/>
        </nextCustomer>
        <vehicle reference="60"/>
      </nextCustomer>
    </VrpVehicle>
    <VrpVehicle id="68">
      <id>5</id>
      <capacity>100</capacity>
      <depot reference="37"/>
      <nextCustomer id="69">
        <id>7</id>
        <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="9"/>
        <demand>5</demand>
        <previousStandstill class="VrpVehicle" reference="68"/>
        <nextCustomer id="70">
          <id>20</id>
          <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="22"/>
          <demand>22</demand>
          <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="69"/>
          <nextCustomer id="71">
            <id>21</id>
            <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="23"/>
            <demand>10</demand>
            <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="70"/>
            <nextCustomer id="72">
              <id>10</id>
              <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="12"/>
              <demand>17</demand>
              <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="71"/>
              <nextCustomer id="73">
                <id>16</id>
                <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="18"/>
                <demand>11</demand>
                <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="72"/>
                <nextCustomer id="74">
                  <id>3</id>
                  <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="5"/>
                  <demand>17</demand>
                  <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="73"/>
                  <nextCustomer id="75">
                    <id>4</id>
                    <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="6"/>
                    <demand>6</demand>
                    <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="74"/>
                    <nextCustomer id="76">
                      <id>6</id>
                      <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="8"/>
                      <demand>7</demand>
                      <previousStandstill class="VrpCustomer" reference="75"/>
                      <vehicle reference="68"/>
                    </nextCustomer>
                    <vehicle reference="68"/>
                  </nextCustomer>
                  <vehicle reference="68"/>
                </nextCustomer>
                <vehicle reference="68"/>
              </nextCustomer>
              <vehicle reference="68"/>
            </nextCustomer>
            <vehicle reference="68"/>
          </nextCustomer>
          <vehicle reference="68"/>
        </nextCustomer>
        <vehicle reference="68"/>
      </nextCustomer>
    </VrpVehicle>
  </vehicleList>
  <customerList id="77">
    <VrpCustomer reference="49"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="74"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="75"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="66"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="76"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="69"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="47"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="67"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="72"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="41"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="42"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="52"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="46"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="50"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="73"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="58"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="44"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="48"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="70"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="71"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="53"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="64"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="62"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="63"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="59"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="65"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="56"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="55"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="43"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="57"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="61"/>
    <VrpCustomer reference="40"/>
  </customerList>
  <score id="78">0hard/-743441soft</score>
</VrpVehicleRoutingSolution>
```

Here is what i tried:

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse("test.xml")
class(xmlfile)
topxml <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
topxml <- xmlSApply(topxml,
                   function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
xml_df <- data.frame(t(topxml),
                    row.names=NULL)
```

Comment: Given the plethora of resources just on SO regarding how to target elements via XPath and the non-insignificant # of questions involving converting semi-complex XML to a rectangular structure in R, what else did you look for and found insufficient to help?

Comment: In the above XML document there is a node - "vehicleList" which doesn't follow a particular pattern and I am new to XML.

Comment: You didn't try _anything_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and modify it as appropriate depending on what is wanted. (The question asks for the node called `VehicleList` but there is no such node in the data and sample output was not provided in the question.)  Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787171/transforming-data-from-xml-into-r-dataframe/40790195#40790195) regarding translating a data frame to XML is very similar.

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlTreeParse("test.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)

do.call("rbind", xpathApply(doc, "//locationList/VrpAirLocation", function(node) {
  data.frame(locationListId = xmlAttrs(xmlParent(node))[["id"]],
             vrpLocationId = xmlAttrs(node)[["id"]],
             id = xmlValue(node[["id"]]), 
             latitude = xmlValue(node[["latitude"]]), 
             longitude = xmlValue(node[["longitude"]]))
}))
```

giving (first few rows only shown here):

```
  locationListId vrpLocationId id latitude longitude
1              2             3  1     34.0      31.0
2              2             4  2     45.0      55.0
3              2             5  3     70.0      80.0
4              2             6  4     81.0      70.0
5              2             7  5     85.0      61.0
6              2             8  6     59.0      55.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Grothendieck, it was very helpful. There is node called vehicleList similar to the locationList which you have used in the solution.